# Why does java on Linux kill Soap-UI's testrunner.sh during a 'Delay' test step?

Tags: java, linux, soapui

I have a Soap-UI project with a simple test suite:

- 1st step: wait 1 minute
- 2nd step: loop to step 1

[image: screenshot test case]

I want to run it in `testrunner.s`h from the command line:

```
testrunner.sh -s"TestSuite" -f. test-soapui-project.xml
```

After a few seconds in the first test step it always crashes with the following message:

```
SoapUI 5.0.0 TestCase Runner
21:31:19,441 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [/usr/home/me/soapui-settings.xml]
21:31:20,076 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/usr/home/me/soapui-workdir/test-soapui-project.xml]
21:31:20,219 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI tests in project [Test]
21:31:20,219 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running TestSuite [TestSuite], runType = SEQUENTIAL
21:31:20,226 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI testcase [Test]
21:31:20,227 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [Wait 1 Minute]
/usr/home/me/SoapUI-5.0.0/bin/testrunner.sh: line 57: 18171 Killed                  java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $SOAPUI_CLASSPATH com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner "$@"
```

**My questions:**

Can somebody reproduce this? Is `Delay` not intended to be used for longer periods? How else could I wait until I do my next request in the test?

**The project xml to import into Soap-UI:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:soapui-project activeEnvironment="Default" name="Test" resourceRoot="" soapui-version="5.0.0" xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config"><con:settings/><con:testSuite name="TestSuite"><con:settings/><con:runType>SEQUENTIAL</con:runType><con:testCase failOnError="true" failTestCaseOnErrors="true" keepSession="false" maxResults="0" name="Test" searchProperties="true"><con:settings/><con:testStep type="delay" name="Wait 1 Minute"><con:settings/><con:config><delay>60000</delay></con:config></con:testStep><con:testStep type="goto" name="loop"><con:settings/><con:config xsi:type="con:GotoStep" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><con:condition><con:name>loop allways</con:name><con:type>XPATH</con:type><con:expression>0=0</con:expression><con:targetStep>Wait 1 Minute</con:targetStep></con:condition></con:config></con:testStep><con:setupScript/><con:tearDownScript/><con:properties/></con:testCase><con:properties/><con:setupScript/><con:tearDownScript/></con:testSuite><con:properties/><con:wssContainer/><con:oAuth2ProfileContainer/></con:soapui-project>
```

**+ + UPDATE: + +**

When I remove the "loop" step, the behavior is exactly the same. `testrunner.sh` crashes before the 1 minute delay is over.

Comment: Actually this is not a complete minimal example. Step two isn't needed to demonstrate the behavior.

Comment: The same test project works as expected in the soupUI front end.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in the Conditional Goto step, you are providing "Condition XPath Expression". The XPath is executed against the previous step context. In your case, the Delay step does not have any context that can be expressed as an XPath, and so testrunner fails. Strictly speaking, this is probably a bug in SoapUI.

If you wish to (dis)prove this, you could inset some request step between your Delay and Conditional Goto, which would have any Response.

This is indeed the preferred (other than a Groovy script) way of causing a Delay in SoapUI.

Comment: Okay I will test this soon. Concerning your question: I need a delay between two tests steps; what other possibility do I have?

Comment: Please do also note that this is only a minimal example. In my actual project I do always have a soap request before the loop. The behavior is the same...

Comment: Make sure the step that generates a Response is *immediately* before the Conditional Goto.

Comment: That is weird. I use delays in my tests up to 5 minutes long with no problem. The only thing I can suggest: upgrade SoapUI and see if it still happens.

Comment: I'm on 5.0.0. Is there a later version? I'm now more facing in the direction of the server config. It's a web server and might have some restrictions...

Comment: OK. I just noticed that the free edition is like a few versions behind.

Comment: Just tried it on my Linux box: cannot reproduce! What Java version you running?

Comment: $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Comment: More importantly: What does SoapUI use? Note that `testrunner.sh` does some "funny" things.